# How to verify if background sync is supported by the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, service-worker, background-sync

I am developing an application that uses service workers to cache HTTP requests from a specific endpoint. These requests should be sent to the server using background sync. I know some [browsers are not supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-sync), but I would like to warn my users that this feature will not be available. To do this, I need some way of identifying whether or not the browser has background sync support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'SyncManager' in window) {
   // service worker stuffs here
} else {
  console.error('Background sync not supported');
}
```